# Understanding FUSE

Tags: fuse

After unzipping FUSE folder, i found the examples folder. This folder has the hello.c file. It also has a wrapper script named hello. I read the description but could not understand it. When we write a code in FUSE, do we need to write such wrapper scripts or are they autogenerated by libtools?

Comment: FUSE is Filesystem in User space.. downloaded the fuse 2.9.7 folder from the net. After extracting it, went to the "examples" folder. Used "make" command, and the makefile in examples folder compiled the "hello.c" program. There I also found a shell script named "hello" which is described as created by libtools. They say its a wrapper script. I am not understanding its purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapper script is autogenerated by libtools.

Although not specific to Gnome, its purpose is described in [Dealing with Libraries](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/dealing-with-libraries.html) in Chapter 3 of [Writing GNOME Applications](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/):

> It appears that libtool has generated some sort of wrapper script
>   around the real executable, which is in the .libs directory. **It does
>   this to make sure the executable can properly find and load the shared
>   libraries, even though the shared libraries haven't been installed
>   yet.** The wrapper script performs a little fancy juggling of paths that
>   wouldn't normally be necessary with installed libraries; it then
>   invokes the executable in .libs for us. In most cases, we can simply
>   invoke the wrapper script as if it were the real executable, passing
>   all the normal command line parameters to it.

*(emphasis mine)*.